# Doctrine YAML generates Datetime instead of Timestamp

Tags: php, zend-framework, doctrine

```
Category:    
  columns:
    id:
    type: integer(11)
    primary: true
    autoincrement: true
    unsigned: true
  name:
    type: string(255)
    notnull: true
actAs:
  Timestampable:
    created:
      name: created_at
      type: timestamp
      format: Y-m-d H:i:s
    updated:
      name: updated_at
      type: timestamp
      format: Y-m-d H:i:s
```

Hi everyone!
Here is my schema.yml and the problem is that when I run doctrine buil-all-reload it generates database but instead of timestamp it adds datetime. Why?
This migh be another question but since it is closely related I will ask here. I wanted to use timestamp because of `on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` Is there another way of doing such thing in Zend or Doctrine?

Comment: Timestamp is the name for DATETIME in Doctrine YAML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should:

1. Use default Timestampable behavior which uses datetime, or:
2. Write your own behavior which uses timestamps so that you can `on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` them ([timestamp from doctrine manual](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm/1.2/docs/manual/defining-models/en#columns:data-types:timestamp))